# React router, route all except Path

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a react router switch, I need any paths except '/terms' to render the CompetitionContent component. And the /terms path to render the terms component.

The issue is that the url '/test' is correctly rendering the CompetitionContent component. But when I navigate to '/terms', both components are displayed instead of just the terms component.

Why would this be happening? It was my understanding the switch would exit after the first match?

```
function Competition(){

    return(
        <div class="container-fluid competition-container">
            <div class="col-12"><Banner/></div>
            <div class="col-12 competition-content">
            
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/terms" component={Terms}/>
            <Route path="/" component={CompetitionContent}/>
        </Switch>
       
            </div>
            <div class="col-12"><Footer/></div>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Competition
```

Comment: add `exact` in all routes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `exact` in `<Route exact path="/" component={CompetitionContent}/>`

After that, you need add more route to redirect all other route to `/`:

```
<Route path="*" component={() => <Redirect to="/" />}/>
```